# How to persist cookie authentication when only using external identity provider without ever calling HttpContext.SignInAsync

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

My main app relies entirely on my external OIDC IDP (IdentityServer4) for cookie + OIDC authentication. It does not have any login page or code, instead it only uses the `[Authorize]` attribute.

So my Startup.cs configuration is very simple like this:

```
 services.AddAuthentication(options =>
 {
     options.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
     options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "OpenIdConnect";
 })
 .AddCookie()
 .AddOpenIdConnect("OpenIdConnect", options =>
 {
      options.SignInScheme = "Cookies";
      //... ...
 });
```

This is the classic setup where the OIDC middleware uses the same `Cookies` scheme after authentication.

It works as intended, but the problem is that the `Cookies` written this way is session only. So every time the user starts a new session in the app, it has to reach out to the IDP (which can keep the user logged in and redirect right back).

Now, to reduce some hits on the IDP, I want to persist the main app's authentication cookie for a period of time, say 1 day.

But I can't figure out a way to configure this. I know normally if I call `HttpContext.SignInAsync` manually like in a login page, I can pass in an `AuthenticationProperties` with `IsPersistent` set to true. But my main app does not have any login page or logic.

I tried configuring cookie expiration time in `.AddCookie()` but it does not help, likely because of `IsPersistent` is not set to true.

I assume there's some other configuration or some events I can hook into to make this work. Your help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can handle the [`OnSigningIn`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.cookies.cookieauthenticationevents.onsigningin) event and set the `AuthenticationProperties` there:

```
services.AddAuthentication(...)
    .AddCookie(options =>
    {
        options.Events.OnSigningIn = ctx =>
        {
            ctx.Properties.IsPersistent = true;
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        };
    })
```